# How to access "gcloud asset" at an organization level from SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I would like to access a list of all assets inside an organization. However, I am unable to access `gcloud asset` at the organizational level from SDK. I can do it without any issues from the console, but I need to use the SDK to create a script.

I have set the **project ID** to the **organization ID**. But I get the following error

```
The value of ``core/project'' property is set to project number.To use this command, set ``--project'' flag to PROJECT ID or set ``core/project'' property to PROJECT ID
```

There is no project ID to be set other than the organization ID.

This is what I see in the console.

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| sample-org | 123456789 |
| project -1 | project-1-34d3 |
| project -2 | project-2-ds2f |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Do not use the Organization ID for the Project ID. For commands that require the Organization ID, you must specify that ID on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

`Project` and `Organization` represent different resources and setting one to the value of the other is meaningless.

Typing `gcloud asset list --help` or Googling "gcloud asset list" provide an explanation:

- [Listing assets](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/listing-assets)
- [`gcloud asset list --organization`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/list#--organization)

```bash
ORG="..." # Your Organization ID
gcloud asset list --organization=${ORG}
```